# Getting stacktrace in logger

Tags: java, log4j, stack-trace

I am using log4j to log my exceptions. I want to log whatever I get in `e.printStackTrace();`
My code looks like this:

```
try {

} catch(Exception e) {
    log.error("Exception is:::" + e);
}
```

But the content I get logged looks like this:

```
2012-02-02 12:47:03,227 ERROR [com.api.bg.sample] - Exception in unTech:::[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@6ed322
2012-02-02 12:47:03,309 ERROR [com.api.bg.sample] - Exception is :::java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

But the content I expect is:

```
java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.api.bg.sample.unGZIP(sample.java:191)
at com.api.bg.sample.main(sample.java:69)
```

I tried `e.getMessage()`, `e.getStackTrace();` however I don't get the full stacktrace. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can view bellow thread. It has complete answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51655824/3073945

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You have to use the two argument form

```
log.error("my logging message", exception)
```

See http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/how-print-exception-stack-trace-using-log4j-commons for more details.

Answer (score 8):

Change your logging statement to:

```
log.error("Exception is: ", e);
```

Answer (score 4):

It is actualy log4j that prevents the printing of the fulltime stacktrace. You should however set the exception as a second parameter for the error method.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the below than e.toString() will be called which calls e.getMessage()

```
log.error("Exception is:::" + e);
```

However, to print full stack trace you can use the below:

```
log.error("Exception is:::" + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
```

where ExceptionUtils is imported as org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils

Answer (score 0):

```
log.log(LEVEL.ERROR,e.getMessage(),e);
```