# How to print stack trace in log file

Tags: java, log4j

I am loging error im my java swing application:             `logger.error("ERROR: " + ex);` where ex is exception

this just print me `13:33:58,964 ERROR PlayOffPanel:292 - ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException`

but I wanna know stacktrace.

my log4j properites:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.maxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.File=error.log
log4j.appender.file.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: You can view bellow thread. It has complete answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51655824/3073945

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have to write

```
logger.error("Error description",ex);
```

Look at the [javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#error%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Throwable%29), the exception must be the second arguments if you want stacktrace.

Comment: What if it's not an exception, you're using `logger.error` for a custom error message and you want to print the stacktrace anyways?

Answer (score 9):

Typically, you can pass the `Throwable` instance to the logger as well, e.g.

```
logger.error( "My custom message", exception )
```