# Regarding logging of log error messages in the custom log file

Tags: java, log4j

I have one query regarding logging is that for loging in my application I am using apache log4j api and I am able to log events of my application in a seprate log file , The query is that in my application let say inside  catch block I normally write e.printstacktrace() which is not proper way since I want to also log my error in the custom log file and not on console , so for this inside the catch block what should I write to log the messages back to the custom log file..  please advise

```
catch (Exception e) {
 log.logError("Error getting  value.", e);
      }
```

and also please suggest how to log other messages like warning and alert one also..!!

Comment: I also found the answers at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347797/how-to-send-a-stacktrace-to-log4j

Answer (score 2):

```
log.error("Error getting value. " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , wat about other messages such as alert and warning also..?