# How to log the full stacktrace?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm using `log4j` to log unhandled exceptions. But how can I log the stacktrace?

I tried the following:

`Logger.getRootLogger().fatal(e);`

Result:
`2013-11-05 14:25:07,078 FATAL root: java.lang.NullPointerException`
BUT no stacktrace! Why?

Comment: have you tried to search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347797/how-to-send-a-stacktrace-to-log4j

Comment: yes, see my comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().fatal(e, e);
```

Comment: ty so much! I completely overlooked that `e` must be supplied as 2nd param in order to log the full stacktrace.

Comment: You're welcome. After working many hours or days at work, we lose ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

field element

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogFactory.getLogger(YourClazz.class);
```

in your methods, simply log e

```
LOGGER.error("There was an error {}",e);
```

and it will print the full stacktrace

Comment: For this, the Original Poster need slf4j. Otherwise, compile error.