# JUnit Test is not returning the full StackTrace from UUT Class

Tags: junit, nullpointerexception, java-8, log4j

I have the following Junit test

```
@Before
public void setup() {
UUTClass myObject = new UUTClass();
}

@After
public void teardown() {
// cleanup
}

@Test
public void testSomeMethod() {
myObject.invokeSomeMethod(); // This is throwing NPE from somewhere inside my UUTClass
}
```

I don't want to use `expected=NullPointerException.class` what I want is log the stack trace from my UUTClass. All I can see is a `NullPointerException` one liner in my test method.

I am using Log4j to log everything and I have got log4j.xml in the search path which does get picked up by Initializer. I can see my logger messages being printed for other items.

How to enable Junit to return/propagate the full stack trace for NPE that's been thrown by my UUTClass? I believe it's probably because the errors are redirected to error console and perhaps not being picked up by log4j (don't know if I explained that right).

As a workaround, I will probably use `printStackTrace()` for now. but ideally I would like to log it if possible.

My Intention is the first understand where in the design I have missed out conditions/constraints which resulted into this NPE and then build more tests to expect certain exceptions.
Regards,

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: yes I am - Running maven test. My Logger is only logging NPE, but it seems calling `printStackTrace()` does what I want. I will need to update my question.

Comment: you could close the question probably.

Comment: it's a user specific problem, not related to API.

Comment: Usually logging frameworks have methods that accept a message and an exception to log the stacktrace for, such as `logger.error("Unable to open connection", myCaughtException)` ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347797/how-to-send-a-stacktrace-to-log4j)). How and where are you logging your NPE? It does not seem to be in the test, so I assume it's in your `UUTClass`, so how do you call the logging framework there?