# Running java application from batch with flags

Tags: java, batch-file, log4j

I hava jar with class `my.package.Foo` inside, containing main method.

What is more i have `Log4j` configurated as a logging system.

I want to print full stack trace while exception is catched, however i read this topic: [log4j not printing the stacktrace for exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295015/log4j-not-printing-the-stacktrace-for-exceptions)
and i think that i need to use a `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` flag.

So i'm trying to call my app with command line like this:

`java -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -cp %JAR_LOCATION:% my.package.Foo`

However i'm still missing stacktrace, i get only short exception message.

Here is my log4j config:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.txt
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-4p %c{2}.%m%n
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-4p %c{2}.%m%n
```

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
set JAR_LOCATION=c:\any folder with spaces\jar
java -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -cp "%JAR_LOCATION:~%" my.package.Foo
```

You have to remove the ":" char from %JAR_LOCATION:%, or use %JAR_LOCATION:~% to de-quote it, and quote it directly at the JAVA command, because the path probably contains spaces.