# Log4j does not log full stack trace?

Tags: java, log4j2, slf4j

I'm using SLF4j with Log4j2.
The SLF4j version is 1.7.22 and the Log4j2 version is 2.8.2.
When I log an exception with Log4j2 in a method, it only logs one line.
I expected the log to show the full stack trace of the exception in my log.
Due to this issue, I am unable to identify the cause of a `NullPointerException`.

Here is my code snippet:

```
try{
    // Some code
}catch (Throwable e){
    logger.error("Occur exception -> ", e);
}
```

The log file only has one line.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

My log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration packages="com.changing" >
    <Appenders>

        <!-- DailyFile & Log file Name format by pattern -->
        <RollingFile name="DailyFile"
            fileName="C:/logs/log.log"
            filePattern="C:/logs/log-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log">
            <PatternLayout charset="UTF-8"
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] [%t] %c{2}:%L - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                    modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.contoso" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="DailyFile" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I have checked that this code correctly writes the full stack trace in my environment and test environment. However, when the same code runs on the production environment, it only shows one line.

If I manually throw the exception, it will log the full stack trace even in the production environment. However, when the `NullPointerException` occurs, it will only log one line.

I have checked that the `log4j2.xml` file is the same between the test environment and the production environment, only the file path is different.

I also tested throwing an exception in a different method in the same class, and it showed the full stack trace even in the production environment. Method A only showed one line of the full stack trace, whereas Method B showed the full stack trace.

```
class A {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(A.class);
    void methodA(){
        try{
           // Some code
        }catch (Throwable e){
            logger.error("Occur exception -> ", e);
        }
    }
    void methodB(){
        try{
           // Some code
        }catch (Throwable e){
            logger.error("Occur exception -> ", e);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: In your A/B testing, was the exception thrown the same?

Comment: Yes, I threw the exception using "throw new Exception("Some message");" in Method A and Method B.

Comment: 1. this is unbelievable (methodA and B look identical!;) 2. there could be some "hidden (jvm) setting": [old but relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295015/log4j-not-printing-the-stacktrace-for-exceptions)

Comment: @xerx593 I have checked that the Java options in my production environment do not include "-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow".

Comment: Log4j 2.8.2 is **very** old and has severe security vulnerabilities. Check with the newest version! Are you logging to a file or `System.out/System.err`? The latter contains not only Log4j's logs but also other kinds of output, e.g. the output of the default [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html), which looks pretty much as what you describe.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks about security vulnerabilities advice. We have scheduled a time for the upgrade. Update my log4j.xml in question.

Comment: @Ziv: what version of Java are you using during development and production? Do you use a `SecurityManager`? Log4j versions before 2.9.0 does not support Java 11+. You can try adding `%ex` to your pattern, while waiting for the upgrade.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz All environments are using Java 8, but the minor versions may differ.
I will check the SecurityManager and update later.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, you can update the logging level for your logger to an appropriate level, such as "DEBUG" or "TRACE", to make sure that the exception is fully logged in your log file. You can also modify your logger statement to include the exception's stack trace explicitly.

Here's an example of how you can modify your logger statement to include the full stack trace of the exception:

```
try {
    // Some code
} catch (Throwable e) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    e.printStackTrace(pw);
    logger.error("Occur exception -> " + sw.toString());
}
```

This will print the full stack trace of the exception in your log file, which can help you identify the cause of the NullPointerException.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The NullPointerException does not always occur. I will add this to my code and wait for the exception to happen again. I will update with the result.